# How to calculate geometric average(pascal or php)

Tags: php, arrays, pascal, average

I wanna solve this problem with your support.
 Assume that, there is an array in variable named $ar, and exist 5 numbers in this array, so i want to calculate geometric average of these numbers through Pascal or PHP programming language. How can i do ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is `PHP` version:

```
function geometric_average($a) {  
   foreach($a as $i=>$n) $mul = $i == 0 ? $n : $mul*$n;  
   return pow($mul,1/count($a));  
}

//usage
echo geometric_average(array(2,8)); //Output-> 4
```

Comment: thanks a lot , this is useful for me , who can do it on pascal ?

Comment: @user1405203: If you understand the algorithm, you can implement it in any language that supports floating-point math. Have you *tried writing a Pascal version yourself* yet?

Comment: Note that the geometric mean of `N` numbers is just the `N`th root of the product of all the numbers.

Comment: I could do this algorithm on php, but me pascal knowledge don't enough to solve that, as i know don't exist foreach loop on pascal.

Comment: @user1405203: Classical Pascal doesn't support dynamic arrays (as a standard data type). You might want to elaborate on how you are going/prepared to pass arguments to the function in Pascal. (And/or, perhaps, specify which flavour of Pascal you are looking a solution for.)

Comment: Should note, that this will work in most dev environments, but it may stop working on production, where real numbers come into play. The fact is that the multiplication part may reach the limit (happened to me) and simply return `INF`. So if you're not sure about that, you're better off looking to do some optimization to the algorythm.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution in "standard" `Pascal`:

```
program GeometricAvarage;

const SIZE = 5;

function GeoAvg(A:array of real):real;
var
  avg: real;
  i: integer;

begin
avg := 1;
for i:=0 to (SIZE) do
  avg := avg * A[i];
avg :=Exp(1/SIZE*Ln(avg));
Result:=avg;
end;

begin

var
ar: array [1..SIZE] of real :=(1,2,3,4,5);

writeln('Geometric Avarage = ', GeoAvg(ar)); {Output should be =~2.605}
readln;
end.
```

If you want to use dynamic arrays this should be done in `Delphi` or `ObjectPascal` for example.

Answer (score 0):

For someone that had an issue with this, as I have stated in the comment to the PHP answer, that answer may not be suitable for everyone, especially with ones looking to find geometric average/mean for large numbers or large number of numbers as PHP will simply not store it.

Pretty easy solution is to split the initial array into chunks, calculate mean and then multiply them:

```
function geometricMean(array $array)
{
    if (!count($array)) {
        return 0;
    }

    $total = count($array);
    $power = 1 / $total;

    $chunkProducts = array();
    $chunks = array_chunk($array, 10);

    foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
        $chunkProducts[] = pow(array_product($chunk), $power);
    }

    $result = array_product($chunkProducts);
    return $result;
}
```

Note the `10` - it's the number of elements in a chunk, you may change that if you need to do so. If you get `INF` as a result, try lowering that.